# kubectl run pod with dynamic script

Tags: kubernetes, command-line-arguments, kubectl

I have a pod which runs my python script on launch. I want to make my `kubectl` command to take an input argument and pass to my python script. here is sample of my pod

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "Pod",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "mypod",
         
         
    },
    "spec": {
        "restartPolicy": "Never",

        "containers": [
            {
                "name": "mypod",
                "image": "myimage:1",
                "imagePullPolicy": "Always",
                "command": [
                    "python",
                    "/usr/bin/cma/excute.py", "argument"
                ]

            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and here is the `kubectl` which i use to create my pod

```
kubectl run -i tmp-pod --rm -n=mynamespace --image=placeholder --restart=Never "--overrides=\"$(cat "mypod.json ")\"
```

is there anyway to pass python script argument along with kubeclt command?

Comment: not sure about the desired output you want, but something on this line may help `k run mypod --image=myimage:1 --dry-run=client -ojson --command python -- /usr/bin/cma/excute.py  argument1   --overrides="$(cat mypod.json)"`

Comment: @P.... thanks for your input. is there anyway i can use my ```yaml``` instead of ```json``` file?

Comment: again not sure I undestand  correctly, however if you mean using a yaml then just change `-ojson` to `-oyaml`

Comment: @P.... whole idea is to run my python script with dynamic argument every time and once script complete delete the pod.

Answer (score 0):

You can see an example of how to pass arguments with python. You can see more documentation in [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm).

```
Consider the following script test.py −
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

print 'Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.'
print 'Argument List:', str(sys.argv)


    Now run the above script as follows 
$ python test.py arg1 arg2 arg3

This produces the following result 

Number of arguments: 4 arguments.
Argument List: ['test.py', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']
```

You can use JSON or YAML formats.

Here you can see how to create a Pod with JSON.You can see more [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands)

```
Create a pod using the data in pod.json
kubectl create -f ./pod.json

Create a pod based on the JSON passed into stdin
cat pod.json | kubectl create -f -

Edit the data in docker-registry.yaml in JSON then create the resource using the edited data
kubectl create -f docker-registry.yaml --edit -o json
And commands to  execute
$ kubectl run NAME --image=image [--env="key=value"] [--port=port] [--dry-run=server|client] [--overrides=inline-json] [--command] -- [COMMAND] [args...]
```